# Run reactnative(Expo) project in chromebook / virtual linux machine

Tags: react-native, expo, runtime-error, expo-go

I am currently using chrome os flex as my enviroment setup in chromeosflex i installed everything related to expo project when i run any expo project it runs fine but can't open
in my phone(expo go app) when i try to run project on my phone i getting error like this[this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugqgO.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the default Connection option: **LAN**, doesn't work for chromeOS ...
To know the source of the problem .. you can read [this article](https://medium.com/@keith.kurak/develop-mobile-apps-on-a-chromebook-really-edd942ecd122)

you should change the default **CONNECTION** option to either:

1. **Tunnel**

> Using the "Tunnel" connection type will make app reloads considerably slower than on "LAN" or "Local", so it's best to avoid tunnel when possible.

2. **Local** if you have your device connected via a USB cable (don't forget to enable the **USB debugging** for your phone)

**if you are using expo sdk-45 or under**:
you can accomplish the above from the **Web UI for Expo CLI**, from the left panel change the CONNECTION option

**for sdk-46 or above**:
since the **Web UI for Expo CLI** is not available any more [read more](https://blog.expo.dev/sunsetting-the-web-ui-for-expo-cli-ab12936d2206) .. you can accomplish the above by the running **npm run start:tunnel** or **npm run start:local** after you have added the following scripts to your package.json

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  ......
  "start:tunnel": "expo start --tunnel",
  "start:local": "expo start --localhost",
  ..... 
  ...
 },
```

Comment: Yes, I need a tunnel on my Chromebook too. I think the officially recommended way to start expo to use npx expo start. You can add on --tunnel flag after it.